"Errno 2 no such file or directory."
I have a script in visual studio 2022 and it is supposed to get the directory of a python file then run it when I click a button. But there is in error "Errno 2 no such file or directory."
Here is the code:
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            string pythonPath = @"C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe";

            string scriptPath = @"C:\Users\Dmitry\Documents\Bots Python\Autoclicker.py";

            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pythonPath))
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Python executable not found: {pythonPath}");
                return;
            }
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(scriptPath))
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Python script not found: {scriptPath}");
                return;
            }

            var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = pythonPath,
                Arguments = scriptPath,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            using (var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

                process.WaitForExit();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(output))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"Output: {output}");
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"Error: {error}");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
        }

I double checked that it is the right directory I copied what I put in the path strings in my code and pasted them into my file explorer and it was correct, but it still doesn't work.

Try moving your script to a folder named C:\Users\Dmitry\Documents\BotsPython\Autoclicker.py (no spaces) to see if it works.

@user246821, if spaces in the path were the issue wouldn't it be better to fix the code so it works instead of having to move files around? Spaces have been allowed in Windows paths for ages.

The "fix" for issues with paths that include spaces in a command line is generally just to quote the path in the command line. ex: start "z:\my docs\thing.exe"

The error is caused by spaces in the path.
You can modify the line:
 Arguments = scriptPath,

->
 Arguments = $"\"{scriptPath}\"",

